# Characteristics of Venus' jet streams?

Tags: venus, planetary-atmosphere

Since the Voyager missions, the atmosphere of Jupiter received great attention, its jet streams made it into [text books on geofluid mechanics](https://www.elsevier.com/books/introduction-to-geophysical-fluid-dynamics/cushman-roisin/978-0-12-088759-0), including their characteristics like the how they meander, e.g. how likely the formation of [throughs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trough_%28meteorology%29) and ridges is.

There is a [Wikipedia page on Venus' atmosphere](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Venus) mentioning the jet streams:

> The upper layer of troposphere exhibits a phenomenon of super-rotation, in which the atmosphere circles the planet in just four Earth days, much faster than the planet's sidereal day of 243 days. The winds supporting [super-rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_super-rotation) blow at a speed of 100 m/s (≈360 km/h or 220 mph)[4](https://doi.org/10.1029/JA085iA13p08107) or more. Winds move at up to 60 times the speed of the planet's rotation, while Earth's fastest winds are only 10% to 20% rotation speed.

This is a good starting point, but I am interested in learning more about the details of Venus' jet streams, like the length scales and dynamics of the jet stream meanders. I have seen images of Venus, but I have troubles already to identify jet streams on many of them, that is why I would appreciate answers with images and/or sketches.

#### References

- [W Rossow et. al.: *Cloud morphology and motions from Pioneer Venus images*](https://doi.org/10.1029/JA085iA13p08107), 1981.
- [Jason Major: *Venus’ Winds Are Mysteriously Speeding Up*](https://www.universetoday.com/103001/venus-winds-are-mysteriously-speeding-up/), Universe Today 2013.
- [Elizabeth Zubritsky: *Jet Streams*](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/10981), NASA 2012.

Comment: No answers, but you and/or others might find these possibly of interest in Space SE: [Would it be possible to “ride the wave” on Venus?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19907/12102) and [A balloon in the Venus atmosphere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46639/12102) and [How did 20 radio observatories track balloons of the 1985 Venus-Halley (VeGa) mission in Venus' superrotating winds at an altitude of about 54 km?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46642) and [Why is there no plan for a Venus orbiter by ESA or NASA?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49069) (yours)

Comment: and [Are there currently any plans for a Venus lander?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12554/12102)

Comment: @uhoh You guessed my thoughts and the background of the question - my dream is a (robot) balloon mission to Venus :-D

Comment: another one: [Around Venus in 8 days by Balloon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2155/12102)